# Mapping between existential types

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

I have several classes like these:

```
class Value[T]

class Container[T](v: Value[T], x: T)
```

Now I want to transform a sequence of `(Value[T], T)`s into a sequence of `Container[T]`s where `T` for each element of the sequence can be different. Such type can be expressed with existentials:

```
def mapContainer(s: Seq[(Value[T], T) forSome {type T}]): Seq[Container[T] forSome {type T}]
```

However, it appears I can't write the body of this function. My naive attempt has failed:

```
def mapContainer(s: Seq[(Value[T], T) forSome {type T}]) =
    s.map(t => new Container(t._1, t._2))
```

The error looks like this:

```
[error]  found   : Value[T]
[error]  required: Value[Any]
[error] Note: T <: Any, but class Var is invariant in type T.
```

I can't make `Value` covariant and anyway this wouldn't be the proper solution, I believe.

That being said, I'm also fine with the result type `Seq[Container[_]]`, but I couldn't find a way to get it as well.

Is it possible to express this without resorting to `asInstanceOf` and such?

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? It seems to work on 2.11.7. At least, I don't get any errors.

Comment: I think your `mapContainer` definition (the one without implementation) should read a little different, shouldn't it?
`def mapContainer(s: Seq[(Value[T], T)] forSome {type T}): Seq[Container[T]] forSome {type T}`

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.10.5. And no, this definition is exactly what I meant. `forSome` declaration should be *inside* the brackets - otherwise it would require *the same type* for each element of the sequence.

Comment: Oh, I see now. The second definition is invalid, of course, I've fixed it.

Comment: As I said, it works in 2.11.7. Is a newer Scala version an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :( There are some dependencies in the project which depend on older scala version and can't be updated now. I'm not sure, however, how it worked for you - I've [just tried](https://gist.github.com/netvl/b425b0e873287c23437b) it in Scala 2.11.7 interpreter and got the same error.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting `s.map(t => new Container(t._1, t._2))` to `s.map { case (v, x) => new Container(v, x) }` ?

Comment: Wow, it seems to be working (in 2.10.5 as well)! I tried it initially, but my IDE yelled at me for some reason and I didn't bother to try and actually compile it. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

Rewrite

```
s.map(t => new Container(t._1, t._2))
```

to

```
s.map { case (v, x) => new Container(v, x) }
```

Unfortunately I do not have an explanation of why the former does not work.

Comment: The reason would be erasure, in `s.map(t => new Container(t._1, t._2))` `t._1` is Value[T] and `t._2`is *T*. In `s.map { case (v, x) => new Container(v, x) }` `v` is `Value[Any]` and `x` is `Any`, because T gets erased in the match. Therefore, the result of the `mapContainer` function then is `Container[Any]`.